# (PHP) What encoding scheme is this (like percent encoding)?

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, url-encoding

(PHP) I came cross this encoding scheme trying to submit HTTP queries to a Chinese website (Taiwan traditional Chinese, or BIG5 which is the encoding of the website).

The search string is
    `兩岸知識產權發展研究`
and it's encoded and posted as the following 
    `col=1&keyword=%A8%E2%A9%A4%AA%BE%C3%D1%B2%A3%C5v%B5o%AEi%AC%E3%A8s&x=33&y=5`

I assume `"%A8%E2%A9%A4%AA%BE%C3%D1%B2%A3%C5v%B5o%AEi%AC%E3%A8s"` is `"兩岸知識產權發展研究"` encoded, it looks a lot like percent encoding but it isn't. I wonder what this encoding scheme is, and how I can encode a string this way in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called url encoding, you can use PHP's [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.urlencode.php) function for this duty. (And check out [`urldecode()`](http://php.net/manual/tr/function.urldecode.php) if you need to decode it.)

Comment: I have tried urlencode, the resultant string is quite different.

Comment: My apologies, I haven't tried but maybe the [raw encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) function will work. It encodes according to RFC 3986.

Comment: It doesn't work either, they encode Chinese characters alike, and spaces differently

Comment: What is your files charset? I am able to get the exact result in your question. (Try converting encoding: `urlencode(mb_convert_encoding('兩岸知識產權發展研究','BIG5','UTF-8'));`)

Comment: Exactly. My files are UTF-8 encoded. I totally forgot about my file charset. Thank you so much !